# universal cover of a finite cw complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that the universal cover of a finite cw complex $X$ with finite fundamental group is also a finite cw complex?

Comment: Yes. The cover is trivial over every cell of $X$ and the lifts of these cells become the cells of the cover.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The fiber over every cell has the cardinality of the deck group, so
$$\mbox{# cells in} \widetilde{X} = (\mbox{# cells in }X)(\mbox{# elements in }\pi_1(X))$$